# Getting subview’s frame in window doesn’t account for navigation bar

Tags: ios, uiview

I’m using the following code to get a UIView subview’s frame in the window:

```
viewToTapOutsideOf.superview!.convertRect(viewToTapOutsideOf.frame, toView: UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!.view)
```

However, when I test it by adding a subview on to my view controller’s view:

```
let testView = UIView(frame: rectToTapOutsideOf)
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

view.addSubview(testView)
```

The subview is added with what looks like the navigation bar’s height added on to the y of the frame.

At first I thought it may be something to do with the layout guides, but printing the length of it equates to zero:

```
print("\(topLayoutGuide.length)”)
```

The view controller is contained in a UINavigationController if that helps anyone

Thanks in advance

Update: After testing the frame is offset by the navigation bar height and the status bar height

Comment: It looks like you're converting it to the rootViewController's view, which is probably a navigation controller view. That's not the same view as the view you're working in, which was probably pushed onto the navigation controller. You need to convert to the view you're actually adding the subview to.

Comment: How do I do this while keeping the ability to work in landscape?

Comment: Device orientation should be irrelevant if you're doing all of this in the root view controller's view hierarchy.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I’ll give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: Your method worked perfectly, thanks